# Read numbers from a file

Tags: c#, file

I have a problem my code is not efficient enough. He thinks he knows the content. How do I write the code so it can work with any file. So he practically only excludes numbers and ignores the words (strings).

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, try to explain better what you want to achieve, and please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a better understanding on how to write good questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
public static int SumUpFileContent(string file)
{
    int sum = 0;
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(line, out int i))
            sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Keep in mind :

- This doesn't work with numbers that have decimals, only integers. replace `int.TryParse()` with `double.TryParse()` if you have to.
- The data must come in a very specific format (i.e. every entry must be on its own line)

Answer (score 0):

From the information you provided you could split the file content in to an array

then for each item in the array use an int.tryParse to see if it is a number. (this is assumed that the numbers are always int)